# How to highlight a single word in a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, swing-highlighter

I want to read in text the user inputs and then highlight a specific word and return it to the user. I am able to read in the text and give it back to the user, but I cant figure out how to highlight a **single** word. How can I highlight a **single** word in a JTextArea using java swing?

Comment: You could use a Highlighter such as a DefaultHighlighter and call `addHighlight(...)` to your JTextArea, but if it is any bit more complicated than that, use a different text component.

Answer (score 17):

Use the `DefaultHighlighter` that comes with your `JTextArea`. For e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter;
import javax.swing.text.Highlighter;
import javax.swing.text.Highlighter.HighlightPainter;

public class Foo001 {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws BadLocationException {
      
      JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
       
      String text = "hello world. How are you?";
      
      textArea.setText(text);
      
      Highlighter highlighter = textArea.getHighlighter();
      HighlightPainter painter = 
             new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.pink);
      int p0 = text.indexOf("world");
      int p1 = p0 + "world".length();
      highlighter.addHighlight(p0, p1, painter );
      
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(textArea));          
   }
}
```

##### [addHighlight()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/swing/text/Highlighter.html)

**Parameters**:

- `p0` - the beginning of the range >= 0
- `p1` - the end of the range >= `p0`
- `p` - the painter to use for the actual highlighting

**Returns**:

an object that refers to the highlight

**Throws**:

`BadLocationException` - for an invalid range specification

Comment: how can I highlighted a text by clicking on it and read it after that?

Comment: @HoverCraftFullOfEels P0 && P1 what exactly means?

Comment: @Volazh: they are just dummy variables, p0 holding the index to the beginning of the highlighted word and p1 the index to the end of the word, as the code shows.